# Why are non-polynomial Legendre functions and Legendre polynomials not orthogonal?

Tags: special-functions, orthonormal, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

The eigenfunctions of distinct eigenvalues for a Hermitian operator are proved to be orthogonal. Why does the same not apply to Legendre polynomials and functions that have different eigenvalues ?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials

Just for clarity, I am talking of orthogonality of non-polynomial solution and polynomial solution here.

Comment: It says in the link "An important property of the Legendre polynomials is that they are orthogonal with respect to the $L_2$ inner product on the interval $−1 \le x \le 1$"

Comment: @MarkBennet : please look at the edited post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An eigenfunction/eigenvalue problem involves boundary conditions, not just the ODE. The proof of orthogonality of eigenfunctions for different eigenvalues essentially relies on the boundary conditions.

Legendre's differential equation being singular at $\pm 1$, the boundary conditions are somewhat implicit: they amount to the statement that the  solution $y$ must stay bounded at both endpoints. This could be recast as the Dirichlet boundary condition for the function $(1-x^2)y(x)$.

[Legendre functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) of the second kind do not obey the aforementioned boundary condition: they blow up at the endpoints, as the linked article shows.

Comment: The proof of orthogonality of eigenfunctions for different eigenvalues essentially relies on the boundary conditions. Can you explain further ? Thank you!

Comment: It involves integration by parts. And for that one needs to know what happens on the boundary.

Comment: Are non-polynomial Legendre functions of the first  orthogonal? Are non-polynomial Legendre functions of the first  singular at the endpoints?